# Using polyfit on pandas dataframe and then adding the results to new columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, linear-regression

I have a dataframe like this. For each Id, I have (x1,x2), (y1,y2). I want to supply these to polyfit(), get the slope and the x-intercept and add them as new columns.

```
    Id        x         y
    1     0.79978   0.018255
    1     1.19983   0.020963
    2     2.39998   0.029006
    2     2.79995   0.033004
    3     1.79965   0.021489
    3     2.19969   0.024194
    4     1.19981   0.019338
    4     1.59981   0.022200
    5     1.79971   0.025629
    5     2.19974   0.028681
```

I really need help with grouping the correct rows and supplying them to polyfit. I have been struggling with this. Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `groupby` and apply the fit within each group. First, set the index so you can avoid a merge later.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = df.set_index('Id')
df['fit'] = df.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(x.x, x.y, 1))
```

`df` is now:

```
          x         y                                           fit
Id                                                                 
1   0.79978  0.018255  [0.0067691538557680215, 0.01284116612923385]
1   1.19983  0.020963  [0.0067691538557680215, 0.01284116612923385]
2   2.39998  0.029006   [0.00999574968122608, 0.005016400680051043]
2   2.79995  0.033004   [0.00999574968122608, 0.005016400680051043]
3   1.79965  0.021489  [0.006761823817618233, 0.009320083766623343]
3   2.19969  0.024194  [0.006761823817618233, 0.009320083766623343]
...
```

If you want separate columns for each part separately, you can apply pd.Series.

```
df[['slope', 'intercept']] = df.fit.apply(pd.Series)
df = df.drop(columns='fit')
```

---

Or from the initial DataFrame  stick with a single `apply` and concat the results.

```
# From initial DataFrame
df = df.set_index('Id')
res = df.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.polyfit(x.x, x.y, 1), 
                                                 index=['slope', 'intercept']))
df = pd.concat([df, res], axis=1)
```

`df` is now:

```
          x         y     slope  intercept
Id                                        
1   0.79978  0.018255  0.006769   0.012841
1   1.19983  0.020963  0.006769   0.012841
2   2.39998  0.029006  0.009996   0.005016
2   2.79995  0.033004  0.009996   0.005016
3   1.79965  0.021489  0.006762   0.009320
3   2.19969  0.024194  0.006762   0.009320
4   1.19981  0.019338  0.007155   0.010753
4   1.59981  0.022200  0.007155   0.010753
5   1.79971  0.025629  0.007629   0.011898
5   2.19974  0.028681  0.007629   0.011898
```